# Python win32clipboard recursive call not working as expected (but actually better)

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com

I made this code

```
import win32clipboard as cb # Used to get the windows clipboard content

def getText():
    errorMsg = '''No text has been copied to the clipboard.
    Copy text to the clipboard and press ENTER:'''

    # The text is in the clipboard
    cb.OpenClipboard()
    text = cb.GetClipboardData()
    cb.CloseClipboard()

    if text == errorMsg:
        raw_input(errorMsg)        
        text = getText() # Recursive call

    cb.OpenClipboard()
    cb.SetClipboardText(errorMsg)
    cb.CloseClipboard()
    return text
```

If I copy "Hello world" to the clipboard and call the getText() twice I get:

```
>>> print getText()
Hello world
>>> print getText()
No text has been copied to the clipboard.
Copy text to the clipboard and press OK: [Copied "Hello" and pressed ENTER]
Hello
```

Now if I try to CTRL-V (paste) into another text editor I get "Hello" - which is amazing, but not what I expected. I expected to have the errorMsg in my clipboard. Keeping the "hello" in the clipboard and call getText() again still prompts the user to copy content to the clipboard.

I don't want to change the behavior of the code, but would like to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the code you've given won't run as is.  I believe the line:

```
if ocrText == errorMsg:
```

should actually be:

```
if text == errorMsg:
```

Additionally when you write to the clipboard you should do this:

```
cb.OpenClipboard()
cb.EmptyClipboard()
cb.SetClipboardText(errorMsg)
cb.CloseClipboard()
```

I.e., you need to call `EmptyClipboard` before setting clipboard data.  When I make these changes, it appears to be working as you described, the error message is in the clipboard.

Comment: Sorry for that. Was using the code in another context and modified it here so it would be more easy to understand what the question is about. I have corrected the code now.

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but it does not explain why the code detect why nothing new has been added to the clipboard since the last call. Event though that the errorMsg does not exist in the clipboard when I paste then it must exist somehow - else the if statement would fail

Comment: I'm not really sure - I think this boils down to something odd happening in `win32clipboard` - it's almost like there are 2 clipboards - its own internal one, and the Windows clipboard.  In your code you are never actually setting the Window clipboard, just the `win32clipboard`.  When you use `cb.EmptyClipboard()` your setting both.